# Grub boot problem on dual boot machine

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, bootloader

I have three systems on my computer. I have had Windows for ages, than I installed Linux Mint and recently Ubuntu. Bootloader is using Mints Grub.

How do I change it so it will be using Grub from my Ubuntu partion? I want to get rid of Mint, but I'm afraid that if I just delete/format Mint partition, I will screw up my Grub and won't be able to boot into any of my systems.

- Windows (sda3)
- Mint (sdb1)
- Ubuntu (sda5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that your Mint drive is on a separate disk (`/dev/sdb1`). If your computer is booting off the thumb drive, you may need to reconfigure your BIOS settings. If you don't know how to do this, consult your manufacturer.

### How to reinstall grub:

1. Boot into Ubuntu.
2. Run the command `grub-install /dev/sdX` where /dev/sdX is the drive you want to boot off of.
3. Reboot into Ubuntu, and verify you are booted off Ubuntu's GRUB, and not Mint's.
4. Remove the Mint partition and then run `update-grub`, on Ubuntu to re-detect partitions. Make sure that you see each operating system in the output.
5. Complete Step 2 again, and verify everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you must re install grub, the easiest way is to log into one of your linux systems, then mount your `ubuntu` partition lets say it is mounted at `/media/ubuntu`, then go to terminal and do:

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/media/ubuntu sda
```

hope my syntax is correct ;)

Comment: It isn't working. I'm getting the following error: source_dir doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory

Comment: I edited, `--boot-directory` ;) if you have two or more hard disks then `sda` might be something else.