# Boot repair did not fix grub rescue prompt, new install ubuntu 12.10

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

Total linux noob. Trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 into an 80G IDE drive. I can boot from the LiveUSB, and install Linux successfully. I shut down, remove the USB stick, and restart. The BIOS screen comes up and then I get an error ending with "grub rescue". I turn the computer off, reinsert the liveusb then boot from the liveusb and try installing Boot Repair. Boot Repair runs and tells me it is safe to reboot my computer, generating this url: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5563668/ I shut down, remove the USB stick and start up again. Same error message ending in "grub rescue". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you expect your computer to boot ubuntu if you remove the usb drive ?

Comment: because i had already installed onto the hard drive.

Comment: If it installed on the hard drive, install grub to the first hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

You must reinstall `grub` and make sure that you install it on correct device (`sda` , `sdb`, etc ...). Have a look at this [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260284/grub-boot-problem-on-dual-boot-machine/260286#comment325707_260286).